# Why is this test condition fails to produce the expected outcome in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement

```
if [[ ! `cat /etc/passwd > /dev/null 2>&1` ]]; then
    echo "not working"
fi
```

I get 'not working' in the output.

But running the `cat` command followed with `echo $?` returns `0`, so I was expecting not to see the output.

Comment: "0" is "false".  Your expression says "if not true, then print 'not working'".  Your script is  doing what you're asking it to do.

Comment: If you are trying to test that the file is readable by the user, use `[[ -r /etc/passwd ]]`.

Comment: How 0 is false? If the command is successful, it returns 0, right? So I am trying to say "If not 0, print not working", but cat returns 0 not anything else. So it shouldn't print.

Comment: @jordanm cat is an example, but trying with "docker exec CONTAINER bash ls" for example same thing.

Comment: `if cat /etc/passwd > /dev/null 2>&1` - checks the exit status of cat. `[[ ! `cat /etc/passwd > /dev/null 2>&1` ]]` checks if the command does not have output, which it never will because you redirect the output to null.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks @jordanm would you explain why? Is `[[  !` not reliable to test exit status?

Comment: It's the backquotes, also called Command Substitution, that you shouldn't use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test the exit status, don't use `[[` and `` ` ``:

```
if ! cat /etc/passwd > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "not working"
fi
```

Backquotes, also called Command Substitution, expand to the output of the command, which is always empty here, because stdout is redirected to /dev/null. `[[ ! $string ]]` is equivalent to `[[ ! -n $string ]]` or `[[ -z $string ]]`, i.e. it tests whether $string is empty, which it always is (explained above).